# Code sample not compiling

Tags: c#

I have been trying to use some sample code provided by Microsoft. I

1. Downloaded the file
2. Hit unblock on the file
3. Unzipped the file
4. Clicked on the solution called QuizGame sample
5. The solution opened in Visual Studio 2015
6. The solution automatically registered hundreds of errors
7. I opened the C# files in the solution explorer to see what was going on and each C# file had tons of errors. Each error was some how related to the System reference.

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The warning was

Warning Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Runtime.dll'

It also shows all the System imports with red lines underneath them. It sounds like it is not recognizing the System reference.

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;

namespace P2PHelper
{
    public class P2PSessionHost : P2PSession, IDisposable
    {

        private Dictionary<Guid, P2PClient> ClientMap { get; set; }

        private StreamSocketListener SessionListener { get; set; }

        private Timer Timer { get; set; }

    public P2PSessionHost(P2PSessionConfigurationData config) : base(config)
    {
        this.SessionListener = new StreamSocketListener();
        this.ClientMap = new Dictionary<Guid, P2PClient>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.SessionListener.Dispose();
        this.SessionListener = null;
    }

    public async Task<bool> CreateP2PSession(SessionType type)
    {
        if (this.SessionListener == null) return false;
        if (type != SessionType.LocalNetwork) throw new NotSupportedException(
            "SessionType.LocalNetwork is the only SessionType supported.");

        this.SessionHost = true;
        this.SessionListener.ConnectionReceived += async (s, e) => await OnConnectionReceived(e.Socket);  
        await this.SessionListener.BindEndpointAsync(null, Settings.tcpPort);
        this.InitializeNetworkInfo();
        return await this.InitializeMulticast(null);
    }

    public bool RemoveClient(Guid clientID)
    {
        return this.ClientMap.Remove(clientID);
    }

    private bool AcceptingConnections { get; set; }
    public void StartAcceptingConnections()
    {
        AcceptingConnections = true;
        this.Timer = new Timer(async state => await SendMulticastMessage(""), null, 0, 500);   
    }

    public void StopAcceptingConnections()
    {
        AcceptingConnections = false;
        this.Timer.Dispose();
    }

    private async Task OnConnectionReceived(StreamSocket socket)
    {
        byte[] message = await RetrieveMessage(socket);
        var newClient = new P2PClient { clientTcpIP = socket.Information.RemoteAddress.ToString() };
        if (AcceptingConnections)
        { 
            if (GetGuid(newClient).ToString() == (new Guid()).ToString())
            {
                Guid newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
                this.ClientMap.Add(newGuid, newClient);
                this.OnConnectionComplete(newGuid);
            }
        }
        this.OnMessageReceived(message, GetGuid(newClient));
    }

    private Guid GetGuid(P2PClient client)
    {
        return this.ClientMap.FirstOrDefault(
            kvp => kvp.Value.clientTcpIP == client.clientTcpIP).Key;
    }

    protected async Task SendMulticastMessage(string output)
    {
        using (var multicastOutput = await this.MulticastSocket.GetOutputStreamAsync(
            new Windows.Networking.HostName(Settings.multicastIP), 
            this.MulticastSocket.Information.LocalPort))
        {
            await multicastOutput.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output).AsBuffer());
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> SendMessage(Guid clientID, object message, Type type = null)
    {
        P2PClient client;
        if (this.ClientMap.TryGetValue(clientID, out client))
        {
            return await base.SendMessage(message, client.clientTcpIP, Settings.tcpPort, type ?? typeof(object));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SendMessageToAll(object message, Type type = null)
    {
        var messageTasks = this.ClientMap.Keys.Select(guid => this.SendMessage(guid, message, type));

        // When all the tasks complete, return true if they all succeeded. 
        return (await Task.WhenAll(messageTasks)).All(value => { return value; });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the exact steps you took? Did you upgrade the project file? What framework version does the project target? Are there any warnings apart from that error? Did you read the readme of the project? Did you install all relevant SDKs? Wchich version and edition of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: And what does _"opened the Visual Studio icon in the file"_ mean? Did you open the .csproj file (C# Project), or a random .cs (C# Code) file? Are you talking about [this solution named "QuizGame sample"](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-quizgame)?

Comment: I (1) downloaded the file (2) Hit unblock on the file (3) Unzipped the file (4) Clicked on the solution called QuizGame sample(5) The solution opened in Visual Studio 2015 (6) The solution automatically registered hundreds of errors (7) I opened the C# files in the solution explorer to see what was going on and each C# file had tons of errors. Each error was some how related to the System reference.

Comment: Add that information to your post and go read the **warnings**. They often point out issues that will resolve in hundreds of errors.

Comment: if this is the only part of the project why not creating a new project yourself? and do a simple copy-paste

Comment: Have you made sure your project has a reference to the System libraries or mscorlib?

Comment: @Cyral you shouldn't have to do that when downloading a project. If it were _that_ broken, I'm sure MS would've fixed their sample code. If there is a _problem_ with the core libraries references, those will be printed as warnings - hence me asking OP twice for that information already.

Comment: _I opened the C# files in the solution explorer to see what was going on_ . dont do it. you should not open files one by one. you must open a file with `.csproj` extention

Comment: @M.kazem OP is talking about .cs files _in the solution explorer_, hence they have already opened a solution or project file.

Comment: @CodeCaster the warning was "Warning Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Runtime.dll' "

Comment: @Spock that warning makes it look like you're missing an SDK. Did you install the "Universal Windows App Development Tools", specifically "Tools and Windows SDK 10"? You can re-enter Visual Studio Community 205 setup to install it, or [download it here](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

Comment: @CodeCaster I downloaded the SDK through the link you sent me. The program is still registering hundreds of errors.

Comment: @CodeCaster I restarted Visual Studio and now it is working. I think Visual Studio has to be restarted for the SDK to load. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not recognizing **.NET** references and namespaces like `System.Generics`, `System`, etc, usualy caused by compiling in **Client Profile** or referencing DLLs that are compiled using different versions of **.NET**.
Go to the project settings and validate you are compiling to the right version of **.NET** with no **Client Profile** turned on.